# I cannot create a manifest.json in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I am trying to start a sample rails app from TheOdinProject. It only creates an app, creates a table for cars, and migrates it. When running the app in the localhost it showed Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError.
Look like when starting the app the manifest.json is not being created. I tried different solutions from the internet including deleting and reinstalling node_modules from scratch, implementing a method to handle the tests, and many more.

```
   {
     "name": "foo",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
       "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
       "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
       "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
      "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
    }
  }
```

This is my package.json. I have noticed that it doesn't have "@rails/webpacker" as a dependency.
Hope you can help me.
This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem guys. It was my node version. I was using the latest but not the LTS, so some packages like the node-sass were not being installed. I downgraded and everything works fine now.